# The difference between triangulation and mesh

Tags: graphics, mesh, triangulation

I have done some computer graphical programming recently, and I have no experience before. I used the library call CGAL(computer geometry algorithm library). Also, I noticed that there is class for triangulation and also class for mesh. Is mesh just a kind of triangle net? Do they have any differences?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Triangulation is one way to mesh the geometry. And it is also possible to represent geometry in different shapes.